# If i make any changes in a datagrid ,then want to display that details to another datagrid

Tags: c#

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nApha.png)If i make any changes in a datagrid ,then  want to display  that details to another datagrid.
If i make any changes in a datagrid ,then want to display that details to another datagrid.

```
DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
dt2 = blinvntry.Searches(txtid.Text, Common.CI(txtproductid.Text));
dgvlast.Columns.Clear();
initgrid1();

foreach (DataRow row in dt2.Rows)
{
    dgvlast.Rows.Add(row.ItemArray);
}
```

Comment: Could you provide some examples or some code what you want to do?

Comment: You should edit your question instead of posting code in the comments. This code doesn't explain, what you want to do.

Comment: dgvfinal is the first datagrid and the second one is dgvLast.dgvfinal contains some information if i make any changes with any row that will have t o display  dgvsecond

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure, what you want to do. You didn't tell us what changes should be tracked.
Because of this I'll show you a simple example how to track a value-change in an `DataGridView`:

```
// Here we initlialize a DataGridView
DataGridView dg = new DataGridView();
dg.DataSource = new DataTable();

// Now we bind a Method to the CellValueChanged-Event:
dg.CellValueChanged += TrackChanges;
```

Now we have to do something if the Event `CellValueChanged` is fired:

```
public void TrackChanges(object o, DataGridViewCellEventArgs args)
{
    int col = args.ColumnIndex;
    int row = args.RowIndex;

    DataGridView source = o as DataGridView;

    object newValue = source[col, row].Value;

    Console.WriteLine("Value '{0}' in row {1} and column {2} of DataGridView {3} changed!", newValue, row, col, source.Name);
    // Here you can modify your second DataGridView. Here an Example, how to move the Changed Value to another DataGridView:
    dg2[col, row].Value = newValue;
}
```

The console-output could be replaced by some actions, like copying data to the second grid or somethig..

Comment: first data grid contains some information like product id quantity etc.if i make  changes with the quantity field the corresponding row should display in to the next data grid.

Comment: Sounds like, this example is what you're searching for. Does it help? If not: Why?

Comment: how can i share  out put window image?that will help you to understand my problem

Comment: @sherin edit your question and not my answer. Post your picture in your question

Comment: i just edited my question please check  and please help me

Comment: i used cell value changed event.